# I have two UK tourist Visas. Are they both valid?

Tags: visas, uk

I have a 6 month UK tourist visa which is valid until 3 April 2019.
I applied for a new one starting 10 April 2019 and today I received it.

I now want to travel to the UK from 7-28 March which would be allowed on my first visa but I'm not sure if it is still valid to travel on.

No one can seem to tell me if my visa is still valid, or who I can ask to check.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can’t find a source but I see no reason why an existing visa that expires before your new visa starts would not continue to be valid. UKVI would certainly be aware of it and I’d expect them to annotate/stamp the existing visa as cancelled in your passport, were that to be the case. One note of caution around your existing visa would be how many times you’ve used it to enter and whether that is consistent with the original application and the Immigration rules V4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Answer (score 5):

Yes, both visas are valid, but be aware that they don't have contiguous validity dates. So you must depart the UK on or before the end of the day 3 April, and cannot return until 10 April.

If your previous visa had been cancelled, it would have had a cancelled stamp placed on it, as in this example:

[image: UK visa cancelled without prejudice]

If your old visa has those stamps, then only your new visa is valid. Otherwise, both visas are valid.